# Python code to extract data from a text file

Tags: python

I wrote this python code to extract data from a text file. This code is extracting only few lines, but extracting all lines in the text file is my requirement. Please help me by suggesting the necessary modifications to this code.
Thank you in advance for your support.

```
import re
fname = input("Enter the filename: ")
try:
    fhand = open(fname)
    for line in fhand:
        line = line.strip()
        lst = re.findall('FAU([^"]*)', line)
        rst = re.findall('AD([^"]*)', line)
        op = lst+rst 
        if (len(op) > 0):
            print (lst,rst)      
except:
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want here. Please provide a short example of
an input file for this and the output that you want to get + how that differs from your current output.

Comment: This question seems unanswerable without further details: Your code has a condition in it - `if (len(op) > 0): ...` - which might not be met by the input?

Answer (score 0):

Use file.read() Function to Read The File

```
file = open("main.txt")
print("Text Of File: " + file.read())
```

The main.txt Looks Like This:

***Hello, World***

The Output Is 'Text Of File: Hello, World!'

Answer (score 0):

1-)The file is opened using the with statement, which ensures that the file is properly closed after reading.
2-)The **if** statement checks if both **lst** and **rst** contain matches, ensuring that lines with both patterns are printed.

3-)The **FileNotFoundError** exception is specifically caught to handle the case when the file does *not exist*.

```
import re

fname = input("Enter the filename: ")
try:
    with open(fname) as fhand:
        for line in fhand:
            line = line.strip()
            lst = re.findall('FAU([^"]*)', line)
            rst = re.findall('AD([^"]*)', line)
            if len(lst) > 0 and len(rst) > 0:
                print(lst, rst)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

Comment: The `if len(lst) > 0 and len(rst) > 0` condition restricts the amount of printed matches even further (the version in the question is an implicit `or` condition). Since OP is complaining over getting not enough data, I kind of doubt this will be a solution?